# Why does node-sass fail on npm rebuild?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules

Working on a ruby project that's using node/webpack and all has been fine but today I've spun it up and get the following error:

"ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--2-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--2-3!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--2-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--2-5!./app/javascript/stylesheets/homepage.scss"

I haven't updated the project nor changed anything locally as far as I'm aware so am pretty confused how this error has started, but either way I did some research of what to do and the consensus seems to be to run:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

However when I do this I get a bunch of errors like this:

```
c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '- 
DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-        
DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-    
D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '- 
D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.4"' 
-I/Users/username/.node-gyp/12.6.0/include/node - 
I/Users/username/.node-gyp/12.6.0/src -I/Users/username/.node- 
gyp/12.6.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/username/.node- 
gyp/12.6.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/username/.node- 
gyp/12.6.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/username/.node- 
gyp/12.6.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/username/.node- 
gyp/12.6.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 - 
mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno- 
unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD - 
MF 
./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   
-c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o 
../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
```

and like this:

```
"/Users/username/.node-gyp/12.6.0/include/node/v8config.h:311:29: 
note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))"
```

And then the following error summary:

```
10 warnings and 8 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit         
(/Users/username/projects/shopfront/node_modules/node-        
gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit     
(internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node" 
"/Users/username/projects/shopfront/node_modules/node- 
gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "-- 
libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/dylantucker/projects/prs-insight-        
ui/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.
```

npm version is 6.9.0
node version is 12.6.0

Many thanks

Comment: have you tried deleting node modules and reinstalling everything

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried doing this various ways but no luck so far. Have just tried again with the following (which you might need to tell me is not the right way!)

brew uninstall node
brew install node
npm install

Then so many errors back (too many to include). Here is the start...

Comment: Oh sorry didn't mean node. I meant deleting node_modules folder from the project and doing `npm install`

Comment: ah thought you meant on my machine rather than at project level.. thanks.. bear with me.

Comment: No worries man. I mean, it could also be locally or on the server. It really depends on where you're building the project currently

Comment: yup same prob: 

node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.4 and node@12.6.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)

Comment: SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:221:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_converters.h:67:
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:22:1: warning: 'ToBoolean' is deprecated: ToBoolean can never throw. Use Local version.
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
X(Boolean)

Comment: Are you sure the packages are still online? The ones it's trying to install?

Comment: I'm just building it in a local directory... I'm not an expert on this yet but can let you know any questions about the environment if it helps. Totally stuck and pulling my hair out! Thanks man

Comment: That first part of the error 'tried to download' would suggest not (just tried https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz  in browser and nothing). It's referenced here when i 'npm install' in terminal:

> fsevents@1.2.4 install /Users/username/projects/shopfront/node_modules/fsevents

I don't even know what fsevents is. Would that be defined in the project somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196806/discussion-between-bidgeeboy-and-jabberwocky).